# Setting HTTP Headers in QGIS 3.22 Białowieża

Tags: qgis, wms, authentication, http, http-headers

In QGIS Buenos Aires there was a way to add HTTP Headers when creating a new WMS Connection:

[image]

However, QGIS Białowieża that option is missing:

[image]

How can I add custom HTTP Headers (cookies) in QGIS Białowieża?

Comment: Was it you https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/23585#issuecomment-1331971185 ?

Answer (score 3):

Try like it was mentioned in this [QGIS Issue #23585](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/23585):

[image: example]

QGIS 3.28.0-Firenze